C# SMBLibrary STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
I know this problem is not about the program but I couldn't solve the issue so I'm looking for an advice. This is the code I use:
using SMBLibrary;
using SMBLibrary.Client;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Type IP Adress: ");
        string ipAddress = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Domain: ");
        string domain = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("username: ");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        GetShares(ipAddress, domain,userName, password);
    }


    static void GetShares(string ipAddress,string domain,string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var smb = new SMB2Client();
            Console.WriteLine("---test1---");
            var b = smb.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);
            Console.WriteLine("---test2---");
            NTStatus status = smb.Login(domain, userName, password);
            Console.WriteLine("---test3---");
            SMBLibrary.NTStatus actionStatus;
            Console.WriteLine("---test4---");
            if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                var shares = smb.ListShares(out actionStatus);
                Console.WriteLine("---test5---");
                foreach (var share in shares)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(share);
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("status : ");
                Console.WriteLine(status.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error : {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}    


I can visit the specified smb share in file explorer but, I always get STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE message when I use this code. I'm definetly sure my credentials are correct. I thought maybe problem is about firewall, EDR or etc. (I'm developing this program for the company I work). So, what's the problem? What do you think about this situation and What should I check? I also tried NetBiosOverTCP but, I got "A connection must be successfully established before attempting login". And I know, Ofcourse, this is perfectly normal because I didnt check for status before trying to login.Thanks in advance.
I tried NetbiosOverTcp but didnt work.
Maybe this helps (I used DirectTcpTransport in this image) :


getshares function does it for me. I check it with wireshark and format is correct domain\username
